# Why am I getting error ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence on insert statement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Here is the code which calls the method which executes the query.

```
try {
            //execute a statement which finds the highest ID in the customer table
            List<String[]> results = dm.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(id) FROM customer");
            
            //gets ID from List of strings
            String[] row = results.get(0);
            int nextID = Integer.parseInt(row[0]) + 1;//adds one to it, this id will be used for next insert statement
            
            //executes an insert statement
            dm.executeQuery("INSERT INTO customer (id, firstname, lastname, address, email, phone)"
                    + "VALUES (" + nextID + ", '" + fName + "', '" + lName + "', '" + address + "', '" + email + "', '" + phoneNum + "')");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Here's the method in the DataManager class which executes queries and returns the results as a List of Strings.

```
public List<String[]> executeQuery(String query) throws SQLException { 
        System.out.println("Attempting to execute query: " + query);
        List<String[]> results = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        try (Connection connection = (OracleConnection) ods.getConnection()){//gets the connection from the OracleDataSource object 
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();//creates a new statement object from the connection
            ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(query);//executes the query using the statement object. assigns results from query to ResultSet object
            
            //gets the number of columns
            int columns = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
            
            //iterates through resultSet and fills results list with results to return
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                String[] row = new String[columns];
                for(int i = 0; i < columns; i ++) {
                    row[i] = resultSet.getString(i+1);
                }
                results.add(row);
            }
            displayResultSet(results);//instrumental, displays ResultSet. used for testing
            
            if (resultSet != null) try { resultSet.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
            if (stmt != null) try { stmt.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
            if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error occurred while attempting to connect to database: \n" + e);
            return null;
        }
        
        return results;
    }
```

The query is executed and the customer is added to the database and yet I get the error
`java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence`

Here's the stack trace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:628)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:562)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1207)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:727)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:291)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:498)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:115)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.fetch(T4CStatement.java:1357)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.fetchMoreRows(OracleStatement.java:4040)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.fetchMoreRows(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:919)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.fetchNextRows(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:825)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.absoluteInternal(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:797)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.next(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:498)
    at data.DataManager.executeQuery(DataManager.java:75)
    at ui.AddCustomer.handleOk(AddCustomer.java:271)
    at ui.AddCustomer$1.actionPerformed(AddCustomer.java:64)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6614)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6379)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4990)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4919)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4548)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4489)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2769)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: Error : 1002, Position : 0, Sql = INSERT INTO customer (id, firstname, lastname, address, email, phone)VALUES (196, 'hudfisuhig', 'fegdsuwiugih', 'dsaasdsadsaddsa', 'asd@sda.sda', '07674916547'), OriginalSql = INSERT INTO customer (id, firstname, lastname, address, email, phone)VALUES (196, 'hudfisuhig', 'fegdsuwiugih', 'dsaasdsadsaddsa', 'asd@sda.sda', '07674916547'), Error Msg = ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:632)
    ... 50 more
```

I can't seem to figure out what is causing this error.

Also I'm new to stackoverflow so I apologise for any formatting issues.

Comment: Read the numeric values using `getInt()`.

Comment: Use PreparedStatements to apply parameters. Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection as it is. **Do not concatenate Strings**.

Comment: When closing resources such as ResultSets, Statements, and Connections use try/finally logic.

Comment: What line is throwing the exception? Please include the stacktrace.

Comment: Just added the stack trace.

Comment: @TheImpaler Better yet, use try-with-resources.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using max(id) to create your own sequence concept. While this makes sense, it's counter-intuitive to normal Oracle sequences. In Oracle, you should have a sequence object that tracks numbers separately and you then use "that_seq.nextval".

You can read more about that here:
https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php

If you do it this way, you also get the benefit of not having to track what the ID number is. (Oracle assigns it to you).

And in high-performance environments, Oracle will also manage the sequence and shard-split it up accordingly so different nodes/clusters can get different non-overlapping ranges so concurrency won't be an issue.